# How to upload file dotnet webapi

Tags: .net

I want to upload a photo to a folder and save the file name on the database but i'm getting Unsupported Media Type error. is there something i'm missing here? thanks

//My Code

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Photo>> PostPhoto(Photo photo, IFormFile? file)
        {
            
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
              var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
              string directoryPath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Images");
              string filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName + extension);
            
              using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
              {
                  file.CopyTo(stream);
              }
              photo.ImageUrl = @"Images\" + fileName + extension;
              _context.Photos.Add(photo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPhoto", new { id = photo.Id }, photo);
        }
```

Error

```
{
            "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
            "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
            "status": 415,
            "traceId": "00-dcf38078e6ee11bdeeb43ce69544b8cb-059dfe7676649229-00"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have appropriate Content-type header and MIME type correctly set.

For example: `Content-Type=image/jpeg`

The Content-Type header indicates the media type, It maybe passing the wrong type there.